# Informix Dynamic Server version 7

Tags: informix

I am trying to install informix dynamic server version 7.
IBM site provide links to "Informix" version 11 Plus.

Anyone knows how can I reach the installation files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informix 7.31 (last in 7.x family) support ended in 2009. So you won't find the installation files anywhere. And you may have troubles installing such an old product on today's operating systems.

There was no "free" version of Informix 7 as there is today for current versions.
If you actually "own" the product you may try to contact IBM and explain why you need it.

It would also be nice to know why you need it? Do you need to restore some old backup?

Regards.

Comment: I just need it for a POC. I will try to get the files from the client who has Informix 7 installed on his environment. Thanks for your reply.